# Is there a better way to give two classes access to each other?

Tags: java

I've been running into problems lately in that my code ends up needing one class to store an instance of another, and that other class to store an instance of the first. 
I feel as if this is poor design and I've been trying to come up with a better design but any one that I come up with will obviously result in poorer performance. (Requiring iterations of lists just to find something, when otherwise I wouldn't have to.)

For example, I'm working on a server-sided system and I will give you the basic outline so that you can see what I mean.

say that the Server class contains instances of World, and NetworkHandler.

When clients connect to the server, the NetworkHandler is notified, and stores the channel in a Session object.
After Login, a Player instance will be created and added to the World.

Here's where things get weird.  I tried having Session holding an instance of Player, and Player holding an instance of Session. This seems to work best, but I feel like there has to be a better way.

As for why I need them accessed from both places, the NetworkHandler is passed the session that's attached to the channel, and handles packets that way. (This must be able to access the Player attached to the Session)

However, sometimes, the World needs to iterate through players and access the Session they're attached to. (such as disconnecting them)

Thank you for any help and if anything is unclear just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give clear design advice without knowing more about your problem / domain but from what you have written, it seems you should separate the “plumbing” logic (networking and server stuff) from the game logic.

A general advice is that if you find yourself stuck in a situation where you can only think of ugly and uglier solutions: Step back a few meters and take a broader look.  Maybe you'll need to refactor more than one class.

That said, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with having two classes refer to each other (though often, it can be avoided).  Consider for example this situation:

```
+-----------+ 1  contains   * +-----------+
|    Box    |---------------->|   Item    |
+-----------+                 +-----------+
|           | 1  is inside  1 |           |
|           |<----------------|           |
|           |                 |           |
+-----------+                 +-----------+
```

Explanation if you don't know UML: The above picture is to be read as “There are *boxes* and *items*.  A box may contain any number of items.  Every item is inside of exactly one box.”

Examples where you need this are not that frequent, but they do occur.  If the two classes are otherwise tightly coupled, this is okay.  Just don't create such dependencies across module boundaries, if all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think if I weren't using an asynchronous networking library like Netty it would be less confusing.  

To give you a background on the way I'm handling networking, I built a decoder based system. Each Session has an instance of a Decoder, and there are different Decoders for different states. (Login, Playing, etc).

I'm not sure how I can split that, so as for now I'll leave those two classes coupled, and hopefully I can think of a better design as I refactor other parts of the system.

Comment: I think I just figured out how I can design this into a better system.  As stated above, each Session can change to a different Decoder. The problems I'm having when needing to Couple Player and Session come in when the decoder goes to the WorldDecoder, which handles world logic. So what I could do is keep everything the same, but give World its own NetworkHandler as well, and Session within that will just be forced to use the WorldDecoder. This will also give the ability to host multiple worlds, and use the Server as a main hub if needed.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative architecture I can think of is "event-driven" which is supposed to decouple objects in situations like this. (Of course, it has its downsides as well, and event-driven code can be very complex).

For instance, instead of iterating through the players to disconnect them, you could put a disconnect event on the queue that all sessions can respond to. The session can put events on the queue and each player could listen only to events from its individual session.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've looked into even driven coding and I'm not sure if it would be best for this project.